Numeración paginas informe Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Estoy con un informe de Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, la única manera que conozco de numerar las paginas es en el encabezado(=Globals!PageNumber), pero hacer eso me descuadra completamente el diseño del informe.
¿Existe alguna manera de poder numerar las paginas que tengo fuera del encabezado?
He intentado de poner parte del diseño en el encabezado, pero tengo datos que van cambiando y si los pongo en el encabezado se quedaran fijos con el primero que recupere.
